# Is there a way to change or specifically mention protocol on RedirectToAction from http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, redirecttoaction

Is there a way to change or specifically mention protocol on RedirectToAction from http to https.
I have a RedirectToAction and I am returning base.RedirectToAction.
For my requirement I need to force it to https protocol - is there a way to do it?
I have search few links but, did not find a solution

```
protected internal new RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(UKey) ? base.RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName)
          : base.RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", UKey } });           
    }
```

Comment: Share your full codee snippet and in addition to this, describe your scenario a bit more in which context you would like to redirect with https.

Comment: I have a method RedirectToAction which is currently defaulted to redirected to http.. I want to make it https based on configuration, if that makes sense. @MdFaridUddinKiron